# virtual Machine Allocate all disk space now

Tags: vmware-workstation

While creating virtual Machine i forgot to "Tick" - Allocate all disk space now.

I have already setted up machine, and cloned several from the one, and made changes. :(

So i was looking for any option so that i could change my machine (thin disk province) to change to pre-allocated where it will be equal to dedicated size.

using: VMWARE workstation 7.1.4
created disk without allocating disk size now need fixed allocated disk size.

any help would be highly appreciated.

To sum up: how to change growable disk to pre-allocated in vmware workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vmware-vdiskmanager -r sourceDisk.vmdk -t 2 targetDisk.vmdk
```

as an administrator while using cmd from windows..

lets say, windows, 7 and we have to open cmd as administrator and cd to the particular location where vmware is installed and run this command,

Comment: when i use this in my computer says "vmware-vdiskmanager not recognized

Comment: @DakshShah add vmware installation path to environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can change the disk type to pre-allocated. You can, however, expand a growable-type disk by selecting Utilities->Expand in the Hardware tab of the VM settings. You can only expnad the disk if the VM has no snapshots and the VM is not a linked clone or the parent of a linked clone. In order to make the newly added space available to your VM, you have to use a disk management tool to increase the size of the existing partition to match the new expanded size of the virtual disk.

Comment: Sorry to bother everyone, i found it after going through vmware manual pdf... 

just giving answer so that others may find it useful if required...

here is how we can change growing disk type to preallocated disk type in VMWare.

vmware-vdiskmanager -r sourceDisk.vmdk -t 2 targetDisk.vmdk

this is done from hostmachine , lets say, windows, 7 and we have to open cmd as administrator and cd to the particular location where vmware is installed and run this command,